# Complete these 3 methods with Linux and Mac code, Memory Info platform independent class

Tags: windows, linux, macos, qt, memory

Take the look at this working class.

I created this class for my project in Qt, because Qt doesn't have its own methods to get
information about memory like: Current process memory, Free Memory or Total Memory.

The class is adapted to Qt, but can be easily adapted to pure C or other api
Its need to link "psapi.lib" or -lpsapi

The problem is I need to complete this class with Linux and Mac code, I think there is
many experienced programmers that can fullfill it with correctly and working code...

the header *.h file

```
#ifndef __CLASS__MEMORYINFO__
#define __CLASS__MEMORYINFO__

#include <QtCore>

#ifdef WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
#endif

class class_MemoryInfo
{
     public:
            class_MemoryInfo( void );

            qlonglong GetFreeMemory( void );
            qlonglong GetTotalMemory( void );
            qlonglong GetCurrentProcesMemory( void );
};

#endif
```

and the *.cpp file

```
#include "class_MemoryInfo.h"

#ifdef WIN32
    #include <Psapi.h>
#endif

class_MemoryInfo::class_MemoryInfo()
{
}

qlonglong class_MemoryInfo::GetFreeMemory( void )
{
    qlonglong _value = 0;

    #ifdef WIN32
        MEMORYSTATUSEX MemoryStatus;
        ZeroMemory( &MemoryStatus, sizeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX ) );
        MemoryStatus.dwLength = sizeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX );

        if ( GlobalMemoryStatusEx( &MemoryStatus) )
        {
            _value = MemoryStatus.ullAvailPhys;
        }
        else
            _value = 0;
    #endif

    return _value;
}

qlonglong class_MemoryInfo::GetTotalMemory( void )
{
    qlonglong _value = 0;

    #ifdef WIN32
        MEMORYSTATUSEX MemoryStatus;
        ZeroMemory( &MemoryStatus, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX ));
        MemoryStatus.dwLength = sizeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX );

        if ( GlobalMemoryStatusEx( &MemoryStatus) )
        {
            _value = MemoryStatus.ullTotalPhys;
        }
        else
            _value = 0;
    #endif

    return _value;
}

qlonglong class_MemoryInfo::GetCurrentProcesMemory( void )
{
    qlonglong _value = 0;

    #ifdef WIN32
       PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
       if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
           _value = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
       else
           _value = 0;
    #endif

    return _value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I won't completely write the drop-in equivalent for you, but here is a basic outline of at least the total memory. This should also work for free memory, but I think you may have to look elsewhere for process memory.

**Mac**

Use `sysctl`; `man sysctl` to see all the options.

```
QProcess p;
p.start("sysctl", QStringList() << "hw.physmem");
p.waitForFinished();
QString system_info = p.readAllStandardOutput();
p.close();
```

**Linux**

Read `/proc/meminfo`. Open that file to see all the options.

```
// The actual command is "awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo", but
// QProcess has trouble with the single quotes. Putting it as a separate
// argument (without the quotes) seems to work.
p.start("awk", QStringList() << "/MemTotal/ { print $2 }" << "/proc/meminfo");
p.waitForFinished();
QString memory = p.readAllStandardOutput();
p.close();
```

Comment: the point is I am not fluently with linux and mac programming, I could go throu linux in worst way but I have no possibility to do on mac.

Comment: ps. I think this class could help a lots of people, but maybe this is not the right place, maybe I should try on forum...